# Is the optimal POVM of a mixed state the same as the optimal POVM of the pure states in its ensemble?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, information

If I have a mixed state, where each pure state in the ensemble has the same optimal POVM (by optimal I mean POVM for which the classical Fisher information is the same as the quantum Fisher information), then is that POVM also the optimal measurement for the whole ensemble? More mathematically, say
\begin{equation}
\rho=\sum_{\lambda}c_\lambda|\lambda\rangle\langle\lambda|
\end{equation}
and we want to estimate a parameter $\theta$ encoded in the state through a unitary generated by $A$
\begin{equation}
U(\theta)=e^{-i\theta A}.
\end{equation}
If for each $|\lambda\rangle$ the POVM which maximizes the classical fisher information (CFI) is the same, then does that same POVM maximize the CFI of $\rho$?